# improve sql query performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following tables:

- Products
- Categories
- Subcategories
- Brands

with the following fields:

Products:

- id
- name
- description1
- description2
- description3
- id_category
- id_subcategory
- id_brand

Categories:

- id
- name

Subcategories

- id
- name

Brands

- id
- name

What I want is to make a query, where the user inputs 1 or more words and then search all the fields I have above.

This is my query now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p. *
FROM products p, categories c, subcategories s, brands m
WHERE p.name LIKE 'word%'
OR p.description1 LIKE 'word%'
OR p.description2 LIKE 'word%'
OR p.description3 LIKE 'word%'
OR (
c.name LIKE 'word%'
AND c.id = p.id_category
)
OR (
s.name LIKE 'word%'
AND s.id = p.id_subcategory
)
OR (
m.name LIKE 'word%'
AND m.id = p.id_brand
)
LIMIT 10 ;
```

Is there any way to tweak this query to make it faster? The Database has quite a few products already, so I suspect the time it is taking for this query to show might be because of that..

Any sugestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p. * 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.id_category
LEFT JOIN subcategories s ON s.id = p.id_subcategory
LEFT JOIN brands m ON m.id = p.id_brand
WHERE p.name LIKE 'word%' 
OR p.description1 LIKE 'word%' 
OR p.description2 LIKE 'word%' 
OR p.description3 LIKE 'word%' 
OR ( IFNULL(c.name, '') LIKE 'word%' ) 
OR ( IFNULL(s.name, '') LIKE 'word%' ) 
OR ( IFNULL(m.name, '') LIKE 'word%' ) 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Or use INNER JOIN in case you cannot have NULL-values in your product-table

Comment: From 30 seconds long, to 0.03 seconds with this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If full text search is not an option and assuming you have appropriately indexed you tables, you could try limiting the resultsets of the joined tables.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p.* 
FROM    products p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT  DISTINCT id
          FROM    categories 
          WHERE   name LIKE 'word%'
          LIMIT 10
        ) c ON c.id = p.id_category
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT  DISTINCT id
          FROM    subcategories 
          WHERE   name LIKE 'word%'
          LIMIT 10
        ) s ON s.id = p.id_subcategory 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT  DISTINCT id
          FROM    brands 
          WHERE   name LIKE 'word%' 
          LIMIT 10
        ) m ON m.id = p.id_brand
WHERE   p.name LIKE 'word%' 
        OR p.description1 LIKE 'word%' 
        OR p.description2 LIKE 'word%' 
        OR p.description3 LIKE 'word%'         
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would replace the conditional joining in the WHERE clause with JOIN

```
FROM products p INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = p.id_category INNER JOIN subcategories s ON s.id = p.id_subcategory INNER JOIN brands m ON m.id = p.id_brand
```

(or use LEFT JOIN if you have NULLABLE FK's)

You then need to have indices on product(name), product(description1), product(description2), (description3), category(name), subcategory(name) and brand(name)